# Function return undefined instead of integer in promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, joi

I have created a validator to verify the down streaming data to server and also checked whether the data is exits in database

model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true,
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    }
},{timestamps:true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('bbusers',User);
```

And A validator

```
const joi = require('joi');
const User = require('./model');

const UserModel = joi.object({
    email:joi.string().email(),
    password:joi.string().min(5)
});

module.exports = (res) => {
    const {error, value} = UserModel.validate(res);
    if(error){
        return error;
    }else{
        User.countDocuments({email:res.email}).then(count => {
            if(count > 0){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And a Last a router for getting invoking the function

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const UserV = require('./UserV');
    
router.get('/register',async(req,res) => {
       console.log(UserV(req.body))
});
```

..
***When Ever I am making a query with a unstructured email value I got an error which is as excepted but Whenever I am making a structured email to check whether the email is there in database instead of getting 1 or 0 I get undefined***

CURL ----

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:3000/register' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "email":"guptaanish450gmail.com",
    "password":"adfdsdff"
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the validator.
If you look closely it will be something like,

```
module.exports = (res) => {
    const {error, value} = UserModel.validate(res);
    if(error){
        return error;
    }else{
        User.countDocuments({email:res.email}).then(count => {
            if(count > 0){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
    return; // The invisible return 
}
```

When there is no error, what you'll get is the `undefined` from the invisible return. At the time when the promise is resolved, your function has already completed its execution.

Make the validator to return a promise in either case and handle it from the router.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const UserV = require('./UserV');
    
router.get('/register',async(req,res) => {
      try {
          const count = await UserV(req.body);
          console.log(count);
       catch(error) {
           console.log(error); // error case is here
       }       
});
```

and have the validator similar to,

```
const joi = require('joi');
const User = require('./model');

const UserModel = joi.object({
    email:joi.string().email(),
    password:joi.string().min(5)
});

module.exports = (res) => {
    const {error, value} = UserModel.validate(res);
    if(error){
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }else{
        return User.countDocuments({email:res.email}).then(count => {
            if(count > 0){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the problem is not solved .. The output is undefined .. Should I use a mongoose validator or external validator like "joi" ?

Comment: I added the Validator in the edited answer. Can you check if that works?

Comment: No it is not working but Thank You 